# Test Class coverage for For loop

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, for

My Trigger

```
trigger ProductDefinitionTrigger on Product_Definition_Detail__c (before insert) {
Set<string> s = new Set<string>();
List<Product_Definition_Detail__c> lst = [select Product_Complexity_Checklist__c from Product_Definition_Detail__c];
for(Product_Definition_Detail__c objLst: lst)
{
    s.add(objLst.Product_Complexity_Checklist__c);
}
Boolean B;
for(Product_Definition_Detail__c obj:Trigger.new)
{
    B=s.contains(obj.Product_Complexity_Checklist__c);
    if(B==true)
    {
        obj.adderror('You cannot create a dulplicate record with same product complexity checklist name');

    }
}
```

}

My Test Class

```
    public class ProductDefinitionController_Test {
    static testmethod void productDefinition(){
       ProductComplexityChecklist__c pc = new ProductComplexityChecklist__c(name='testPComplex',Flag_for_Edit__c=false,Market_Segment__c='Small',Product_Type__c='New',Benefits_Coding__c='New',Network_Id__c='New',Nasco_Code__c='New');
       insert pc;
       Product_Generation_Grid__c PG = new Product_Generation_Grid__c(Name='Test Aruna',Product_Complexity_Checklist__c=pc.id,Flag__c='providerNetwork',Product_Approval_Status__c='Approved');
       insert PG;

        Product_Definition_Detail__c pd = new Product_Definition_Detail__c(Product_Complexity_Checklist__c=pc.id,Market_Segment__c='Small',Product_Type__c='New',Product_Template__c='Master Template');
         insert pd;
system.debug('pdddd'+pd);

         }
         }
```

The code covered

[image]

Their is a record inserted but it is not entering the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *before insert* trigger. This means that the data is not yet committed to the database, and therefore can't be queried, even in the same transaction. You would need to insert at least *two* records in order to cover this code 100%.

Also, your code will not scale well; do not query the *entire database* just to find one record. Your trigger should look more like this:

```
trigger ProductDefinitionTrigger on Product_Definition_Detail__c (before insert) {
Set<string> s = new Set<string>(), dupes = new Set<String>();
for(Product_Definition_Detail__c objLst: Trigger.new)
{
    s.add(objLst.Product_Complexity_Checklist__c);
}
List<Product_Definition_Detail__c> lst = [select Product_Complexity_Checklist__c from Product_Definition_Detail__c WHERE Product_complexity_checklist__c = :s];
for(Product_Definition_Detail__c record: lst) {
  dupes.add(record.Product_Complexity_Checklist__c);
}
for(Product_Definition_Detail__c obj:Trigger.new)
{
    if(dupes.contains(obj.Product_Complexity_Checklist__c))
    {
        obj.adderror('You cannot create a dulplicate record with same product complexity checklist name');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Would need to insert a list of Product_Definition_Detail__c in test class then it will Cover.